# Union de 3 tablas con campos a 0

Tags: sql

Antes de nada, pongo en contexto.
Tengo 3 tablas: `persona`, `medico` y `hospital`. En `medico` hay `foreign key` de `persona` y en `persona` hay `foreign key` de `hospital`,a grosso modo.
`Medico` tiene un campo de `especialidad`.

Debo sacar los médicos que hay por cada especialidad en cada hospital, incluyendo las especialidades en las que determinado hospital tenga 0 empleados, pero no consigo sacar esas especialidades que tengan 0 empleados, sólo muestra las que tengan algún empleado. La consulta que llevo realizada es la siguiente.

```
SELECT COUNT(medico.COD_MEDICO), h.NOMBRE, medico.ESPECIALIDAD
FROM persona p 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN hospital h 
        ON p.COD_HOSPITAL=h.COD_HOSPITAL 
    RIGHT OUTER JOIN medico 
        ON p.COD_PERSONA=medico.COD_PERSONA
GROUP BY ESPECIALIDAD, h.NOMBRE
```

Comment: Esto: *«En medico hay foreign key de persona y en persona hay foreign key de hospital...»*  no es correcto desde un punto de vista lógico. Debería ser al revés. ¿Todas las personas son médicos? NO. ¿Todos los médicos son personas? SÍ. ¿Todos los médicos tienen que ver con hospital? SÍ. Entonces la relación debería ser `personas_médicos` por un lado, y `médicos_hospital`, no personas_hospital. Otra cosa a tener en cuenta es que un médico puede estar en varios hospitales y tener varias especialidades. Aquí se va a requerir una relación muchos a muchos para resolver el problema.

Comment: No es así del todo, en la tabla persona están en si los trabajadores del hospital, no sólo los médicos, por eso la relación es persona_hospital. También aclaro que el supuesto indica que una persona está asignada un único hospital, de ahí la foreign key en la tabla persona con el campo de id_hospital. Perdón por la ambigüedad de la explicación.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar la estructura de las tablas, la puedes obtener haciendo un `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombreDeLaTabla` ... puede que tengas razón, aunque no sé. Leí que pusiste un campo `ENUM´ en `medico`, ¿por qué tomaste esa decisión? Yo habría creado una tabla que asocie a médicos y a especialidades. ¿Se puede modificar el modelo de datos o es fijo?

Comment: Es un modelo fijo, es un ejercicio propuesto por mi profesora que ni ella mismo ha sabido responder. De todas formas ya tengo la solución creo: `SELECT H.NOMBRE, COUNT(M.COD_MEDICO), H.COD_HOSPITAL` `FROM PERSONA P` `LEFT JOIN MEDICO M ON M.COD_PERSONA=P.COD_PERSONA` `RIGHT JOIN hospital H ON H.COD_HOSPITAL=p.COD_HOSPITAL` `GROUP by p.COD_HOSPITAL` Perdón por el formato del comentario, aun no me queda muy claro

Answer (score 0):

Según las instrucciones que has dado he creado una solución, he utilizado las left join para coger todas las especialidades y con una consulta en el select puedes seleccionar el count de los elementos que coincidan con tus requisitos.

[http://tpcg.io/koEBTm](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/tpcg.php?p=koEBTm)

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
/* Create a table called NAMES */
CREATE TABLE hospital(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);
CREATE TABLE medico(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text, idHospital integer, idEspecialidad integer);
CREATE TABLE especialidad(Id integer PRIMARY KEY, Name text);
/* Create few records in this table */
INSERT INTO hospital VALUES(1,'San fernando');
INSERT INTO hospital VALUES(2,'La paz');

INSERT INTO medico VALUES(1,'Frank', 1, 2);
INSERT INTO medico VALUES(2,'Jane', 2, 3);
INSERT INTO medico VALUES(3,'Robert', 1, 3);

INSERT INTO especialidad VALUES(1,'Brazos');
INSERT INTO especialidad VALUES(2,'Pierna');
INSERT INTO especialidad VALUES(3,'Cabeza');
COMMIT;

SELECT e.name, h.name, (select count(m.id) from medico m where m.idEspecialidad = e.id AND m.idHospital = h.id) as counter
FROM especialidad e
LEFT JOIN medico me
    on me.idEspecialidad = e.id
LEFT JOIN hospital h
    on h.id = me.idHospital
GROUP BY e.name, h.name
```

Sino acabas de ver como hacerlo pon la información de las tablas completa y lo realizare con esos datos.

Comment: Tu diseño se queda corto. Es muy probable que un mismo médico trabaje en varios hospitales y que tenga varias especialidades. Se requieren por tanto dos relaciones *muchos a muchos* que expresen `medico_hospital` y `medico_especialidad`.

Comment: Especialidad es un campo de tipo enumeración en médico.

Comment: Pon la información completa de las tablas y lo hare con ellas, algo parecido a lo que he hecho @mut3dd

Comment: He respondido arriba con la posible solucion, la informacion de tablas es muy simple: `CREATE TABLE HOSPITAL (
 COD_HOSPITAL,NOMBRE ,NUM_PLAZAS
);

CREATE TABLE PERSONA (
 COD_PERSONA,DNI,COD_HOSPITAL,NOMBRE,APELLIDO1,APELLIDO2,SALARIO,FUNCION ENUM ('CONSERJE', 'MEDICO', 'DIRECTOR'),
);

CREATE TABLE MEDICO (
 COD_MEDICO,COD_PERSONA,ESPECIALIDAD ENUM('PSIQUIATRA', 'CIRUJANO', 'DERMATÓLOGO'),
);` Perdón por el formato del comentario, aun estoy aprendiendo esto

Comment: @mut3dd Ese enum no tiene mucho sentido, un enum te perjudicara mas a largo plazo que crear una tabla nueva ya que en el caso de querer añadir un caso nuevo debes hacer un alter de la tabla que consume mas recursos que hacer un simple insert. Mi consejo es que crees una tabla especialidad con una FK a la tabla medico de esta manera con el SQL que te puse más arriba podras mostrar todas las espicalidades. CREATE TABLE medico ( COD_MEDICO integer PRIMARY KEY,COD_PERSONA integer, codEspecialidad Integer ); CREATE TABLE hospital ( COD_especialidad integer PRIMARY KEY, NOMBRE text);

Comment: @solamente Si, me gusta más esa opción, pero es una estructura de tablas fija de un ejercicio de clase planteada por nuestra profesora y tenía dudas con esa consulta. Sí de mi dependiese la estructura la hubiese creado de forma bastante diferente y como tú has dicho, no hubiera hecho esa enumeración (ni ninguna). Muchas gracias igualmente por la ayuda!